# Обучение / создание каскада для компьютерного зрения

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, opencv

я пытался сделать свой собственный каскад для компьюиерного зрения по статьям, но почти везде используется Linux, я использую windows. Что нужно делать, если начинать прям с полного нуля? Использую opencv

Answer (score 1):

Отличия Linux и Windows только в подключении камеры, например, DSHOW или V4L - две строчки исправишь, а дальше работа в Python достаточно унифицированна.